# GET data from Express to Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, web

Can you guys please help me. I've been trying to learn angular recently and I came up with this little problem that I can't dispaly data from server in simple angular app.

I've created an express local-host server and in folder of my server I have a folder with 3 .js files containing data for my app. Let's just say one of them is called "menu" and contains array of objects with properties like: "name", "price", "ingredients".

```
module.exports = [
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Margherita',
    ingredients: [1, 2],
    price: 14.90
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Funghi ',
    ingredients: [1, 2, 3],
    price: 16.90
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Vesuvio',
    ingredients: [1, 2, 4],
    price: 17.90
}];
```

After launching a server on port :8080  in my web browser I'm typing: "localhost:8080/menu" and I have a view of all my objects.

Now in my angular app I've created a service

```
 app.factory('menu', ['$http', function($http) { 
 return 
 $http.get('http://localhost:8080/menu') 
        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
          return err; 
        }); 
  }]);
```

and injected it to my MainController.js

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','menu', function($scope, menu) {
  $scope.today = new Date();

  menu.success(function(data){
  $scope.pizzaMenu = data;
   });

}]);
```

index.html

```
 <div class="appetizers row" ng-repeat="pizza in pizzaMenu.module.export">
          <div class="item col-md-9">
            <h3 class="name"> {{pizza.name}} </h3>
            <p class="description"> {{pizza.ingredients}} </p>
          </div>
          <div class="price col-md-3">
            <p class="price">  {{pizza.price}} </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

What is wrong with my thinking and my code?

Kind regards,
Mikolaj

Comment: Is there an actual problem you're seeing? Did you look for errors in your browser's console?

Comment: @Phil  the consol log shows " XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/menu. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
 ”

Comment: Search for that error message. You will find many duplicate questions with good answers

Answer (score 0):

The problem I believe is that you're using jQuery type callback syntax.  You need to use `.then` instead of `.success` and `.catch` instead of `.error`.

```
app.factory('menu', ['$http', function($http) { 
 return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/menu').catch(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    throw data;
 });

}]);



menu.then(function(data){
  $scope.pizzaMenu = data;
});
```

Comment: Don't throw away the error like that, otherwise the promise will be considered *resolved*.

Comment: You can also `return $q.reject(data)` to keep the promise rejection going

Comment: Is this the right way to connect to server by creating service ? In general ?

Comment: Typically you can create a service which would manage an api resource like your menu.  The service should be responsible for getting data from the server, knowing when it needs to be refreshed, updated, created etc.

Comment: and what is the best way to do this kind of stuff ? what are the best practices ?

Comment: I would look into using angular $resource service.  Its a more elegant wrapper than the $http service:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource